# Url changed automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, redirect

This is my route :

```
routes.MapRoute(
"LastTwoRoute",
"thong-ke-ket-qua-xo-so-2-so-cuoi/{cityID}/{numbers}/{days}/{onlySpecial}",
new { controller = "LastTwo", action = "Index", 
        cityID = "MB", 
        numbers = "",
        days = 1000,
        onlySpecial = false
});
```

This is the controller :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string cityID, string numbers, int days, bool onlySpecial)
{

    LastTwoParameters lastTwoParameters = new LastTwoParameters();
    lastTwoParameters.listCities = Common.GetDropDownCitiesList();
    lastTwoParameters.listLastTwoResult = new List<getReport_LastTwo_Result>();

    if (TempData["Redirection"] != null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(numbers) )
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityID) && days > 0)
        {
            using (KQXS context = new KQXS())
            {
                lastTwoParameters.listLastTwoResult = context.getReport_LastTwo(cityID, numbers, days, onlySpecial).ToList();
            }
        }

    }
    return View(lastTwoParameters);
}

[HttpPost]//Run action method on form submission
public ActionResult Index(List<Cities> c, string cityID, string numbers, int days, bool onlySpecial)
{
    TempData["Redirection"] = true; 
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { cityID = cityID, numbers = numbers, days = days, onlySpecial = onlySpecial });
}
```

When I first access the controller, the url is :

```
http://example.com/thong-ke-ket-qua-xo-so-2-so-cuoi
```

When I choose the arbitrary parameters from the parameter panel and click submit :

```
http://example.com/thong-ke-ket-qua-xo-so-2-so-cuoi/MB/5/70/True
```

But for some reasons, sometimes the url becomes this after submiting :

```
http://example.com/LastTwo?cityID=NBD&numbers=&days=70&onlySpecial=False
```

The `thong-ke-ket-qua-xo-so-2-so-cuoi` part was replaced with the controller name : `LastTwo` and the parameter part becomes `?para=value`

Why is this happening and how do I prevent this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use RedirectToRoute instaed of using RedirectToAction in you post action to persist URLs state. Like below

```
return RedirectToRoute("LastTwoRoute",new { cityID = cityID, numbers = numbers, days = days, onlySpecial = onlySpecial });
```

For more detail checkout this link
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx/